# How to adjust parameters in TDengine database?

Tags: sql, database, iot, tdengine

When I use "show databases" command in taos shell, I see there are a lot of database parameters, like keep, days, cache, blocks

```sql
taos> show databases;
              name              |      created_time       |   ntables   |   vgroups   | replica | quorum |  days  |   keep0,keep1,keep(D)    |  cache(MB)  |   blocks    |   minrows   |   maxrows   | wallevel |    fsync    | comp | cachelast | precision | update |   status   |
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 test                           | 2021-05-26 17:33:17.338 |           1 |           1 |       1 |      1 |     10 | 3650,3650,3650           |          16 |           6 |         100 |        4096 |        1 |        3000 |    2 |         0 | ms        |      0 | ready      |

Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.001774s)
```

To make best practice of TDengine database, how should I adjust these databases parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can try "ALTER DATABASE db_name KEEP value;".

Comment: I know this command, but my question is more like how to adjust these parameters to make TDengine database have the best performance.